# pandas: how to generate a new column to get another column's value of last date-time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe like below:

```
obj_id   data_date   value
4        2010-11-01  59500    
2        2011-10-01  35200 
4        2012-07-31  24860   
1        2013-07-28  15860
2        2014-10-15  200200
```

how i can generate a new column to record the an object's last time value? if an object hasn't appeared before, it should set the default value as 0. the output should be like this:

```
obj_id   data_date   value    last_value
4        2010-11-01  59500    0
2        2011-10-01  35200    0
4        2012-07-31  24860    59500
1        2013-07-28  15860    0
2        2014-10-15  200200   35200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `groupby().shift()`

```
df['last_value'] = df.groupby('obj_id')['value'].shift(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
   obj_id   data_date   value  last_value
0       4  2010-11-01   59500           0
1       2  2011-10-01   35200           0
2       4  2012-07-31   24860       59500
3       1  2013-07-28   15860           0
4       2  2014-10-15  200200       35200
```

Comment: cool. i haven't used shift before.  but i can see it's benefits